# ASP.Net Dashboard taking too much load time

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, visual-studio-2010, linq-to-entities

I'm using ASP.Net along with EF5 to develop an application. I'm using MySQL for database. I have a dashboard which contains 2 graphs and a map. Also some counts down the form. It also contains drop down criteria for filtering.
Page is taking 4 minutes to load. I have used optimized queries.
As data increases load time will increase as well. I have to optimize it.
Queries are working fine but foreach iterations are taking too much time.

I have 4 departments and every department clause has some categories inside it's clause under foreach loop.

```
                if (Department1 == "Motor Vehicle Registration")
                {
                    UniqueNos.Add(item.Number);
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.FeedbackCategory) != true)
                    {
                        if (item.FeedbackCategory == "Appreciation")
                        {
                            if (MVRNos.Contains(item.Number) != true)
                            {
                                a++;
                                AllCategories.Add(item.FeedbackCategory);
                            }
                        }
                        else if (item.FeedbackCategory == "Corruption - General (Relevant to the department)")
                        {
                            if (MVRNos.Contains(item.Number) != true)
                            {
                                b++;
                                MVRNos.Add(item.Number);
                                AllCategories.Add(item.FeedbackCategory);
                            }
                        }
                        else if (item.FeedbackCategory == "Corruption - Specific (Relevant to the department)")
                        {
                            if (MVRNos.Contains(item.Number) != true)
                            {
                                c++;
                                MVRNos.Add(item.Number);
                                AllCategories.Add(item.FeedbackCategory);
                            }
                        }
                        else if (item.FeedbackCategory == "Corruption in the other office")
                        {
                            if (MVRNos.Contains(item.Number) != true)
                            {
                                dd++;
                                MVRNos.Add(item.Number);
                                AllCategories.Add(item.FeedbackCategory);
                            }
                        }
                        else if (item.FeedbackCategory == "Delay - Document/File not received")
                        {
                            if (MVRNos.Contains(item.Number) != true)
                            {
                                e++;
                                MVRNos.Add(item.Number);
                                AllCategories.Add(item.FeedbackCategory);
                            }
                        }
                        else if (item.FeedbackCategory == "Delay - Number Plate Not Received")
                        {
                            if (MVRNos.Contains(item.Number) != true)
                            {
                                f++;
                                MVRNos.Add(item.Number);
                                AllCategories.Add(item.FeedbackCategory);
                            }

                        }
                        else if (item.FeedbackCategory == "Delay - Others")
                        {
                            if (MVRNos.Contains(item.Number) != true)
                            {
                                g++;
                                MVRNos.Add(item.Number);
                                AllCategories.Add(item.FeedbackCategory);
                            }

                        }
                        if (item.FeedbackCategory == "Don't Know")
                        {
                            if (MVRNos.Contains(item.Number) != true)
                            {
                                h++;
                                MVRNos.Add(item.Number);
                                AllCategories.Add(item.FeedbackCategory);
                            }

                        }
                        if (item.FeedbackCategory == "Further inquiry required")
                        {
                            if (MVRNos.Contains(item.Number) != true)
                            {
                                i++;
                                MVRNos.Add(item.Number);
                                AllCategories.Add(item.FeedbackCategory);
                            }

                        }
                        if (item.FeedbackCategory == "Others")
                        {
                            if (MVRNos.Contains(item.Number) != true)
                            {
                                j++;
                                MVRNos.Add(item.Number);
                                AllCategories.Add(item.FeedbackCategory);
                            }

                        }
                        if (item.FeedbackCategory == "Other complaints (relevant to the department)")
                        {
                            if (MVRNos.Contains(item.Number) != true)
                            {
                                k++;
                                MVRNos.Add(item.Number);
                                AllCategories.Add(item.FeedbackCategory);
                            }

                        }
                        if (item.FeedbackCategory == "Complaints (relevant to the other department)")
                        {
                            if (MVRNos.Contains(item.Number) != true)
                            {
                                l++;
                                MVRNos.Add(item.Number);
                                AllCategories.Add(item.FeedbackCategory);
                            }

                        }
                        if (item.FeedbackCategory == "Suggestion (Relevant to the department)")
                        {
                            if (MVRNos.Contains(item.Number) != true)
                            {
                                m++;
                                MVRNos.Add(item.Number);
                                AllCategories.Add(item.FeedbackCategory);
                            }

                        }
                        if (item.FeedbackCategory == "Suggestion (Relevant to the other department)")
                        {
                            if (MVRNos.Contains(item.Number) != true)
                            {
                                n++;
                                MVRNos.Add(item.Number);
                                AllCategories.Add(item.FeedbackCategory);
                            }

                        }
                        if (item.FeedbackCategory == "Treatment (Unfair) to Customers")
                        {
                            if (MVRNos.Contains(item.Number) != true)
                            {
                                o++;
                                MVRNos.Add(item.Number);
                                AllCategories.Add(item.FeedbackCategory);
                            }

                        }
                        if (item.FeedbackCategory == "Wrong Person")
                        {
                            if (MVRNos.Contains(item.Number) != true)
                            {
                                p++;
                                MVRNos.Add(item.Number);
                                AllCategories.Add(item.FeedbackCategory);
                            }
                        }
                        if (item.FeedbackCategory == "Irrelevant")
                        {
                            if (MVRNos.Contains(item.Number) != true)
                            {
                                q++;
                                MVRNos.Add(item.Number);
                                AllCategories.Add(item.FeedbackCategory);
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Where's the actual foreach and where's the collection you're interating over? You seem to have left out that code?

Comment: That is too long to be post here

Comment: You said the iteration is the problem but then don't post the actual beginning of the loop. You don't see the problem with that?